# android EditText focus behavior

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I thought this would be a simple thing to implement, but apparently not. I have a Fragment with 2 editTexts and 1 TextView. all have custom Drawables for background.  Here's the behavior I'm looking for:

1. when fragment opens, nothing has the focus - ***that's working***
2. when you tap on either of the edits, it gets the focus, all text is selected, and softKeyboard opens in number mode - ***that's working too***
3. after entering the new number, when the blue key in the bottom right corner of the softkeyboard is clicked (tab or checkmark symbol), the softkeyboard closes and nothing has the focus - no blinking cursor. - ***that's what I can't get to work***.
   Please help. Kotlin or Java OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement this logic (you can upgrade it further if you want, it's just an example)

Layout:

```
...

        <View
            android:id="@+id/f_c_focus_view"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number"/>
...
```

In layout you can see hidden 'focus' view, it necessary for interception focus, because if you have an EditText as first component of the view it always will receive the focus. My EditText components have an `imeOptions="actionDone"` which I will handle in code further, you can have different imeOptions.

Code:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

    ...

        focusView.requestFocus() // intercept focus on view created

        editText1.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, _ ->
            when(actionId) {
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> { // handle checkmark key press on the keyboard
                    v.clearFocus()
                    hideKeyBoard(v)
                }
            }

            false
        }

        editText2.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, _ ->
            when(actionId) {
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
                    v.clearFocus()
                    hideKeyBoard(v)
                }
            }

            false
        }

   ...
}

private fun hideKeyBoard(v: View) {
    val imm = context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Artem. After a bit of a nap, I came up with a solution somewhat similar to yours but without the extra view. I decided I wasn't so much worried about the focus as I was about the cursor.
I used the OnEditorActionListener to hide the cursor on IME_ACTION_DONE. I used OnClick to show it again.  I had to add selectAll to the onClick to handle when the user went into the same edit twice in a row (since technically focus had not changed)